# Is there a camera calibration matrix database?

Tags: image-processing, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration, distortion

Is there a free-access database containing camera calibration parameters (camera matrices, intrinsic and extrinsic parameters) for the most popular devices?

I'm particularly interested in mobile-phone cameras or tablets with fixed focal length more than DSC's or DSLR's.

The idea is that an app using computer vision algorithms could access the database and download the parameters and be able to work right away, instead of making the users to calibrate their devices (and avoid having to calibrate every possible device myself)

*I'm not interested in the micro-variations that might exist between different devices of the same model, average values are ok*

Comment: Generally, over time calibration becomes invalid because parts do move, even if they are supposed to be fixed. If you want to do any kind of precision measurements, you want to re-calibrated your camera just before you use it.

Comment: I'm also looking for this. Did you find anything?

Comment: Just to note that the extrinsic parameters describe the camera orientation and position in the scene, and are not dependent on the camera model at all, but on how you place it.

Answer (score 1):

On most smartphones you can ask the camera device for its parameters (that's how they get written in the EXIF headers of the images). Or you can read them from EXIF yourself.

Answer (score 1):

there is the web based calibration service at https://www.calibdb.net/. It remembers finished calibrations, so it also acts as a database.