# How to handle camera calibration for opencv at scale

Tags: ios, opencv, camera-calibration, arkit, opencv-solvepnp

I'm using openCV solvePNP algorithm to detect and measure a device's pose from an AR Marker using openCV. My end goal is to get very precise real-world measurements. My app is likely to run on a wide range of iOS and Android devices.

I understand that I need to pass a camera calibration for pose estimation to work accurately. I can print out a checkerboard and measure these values on my own development device, but what's the best way to handle calibration with applications more widely distributed to a large number of users/devices?

Could there possibly be camera calibration tables for various devices I can look up?

Comment: googling *camera intrinsics database* gave me https://github.com/BloodAxe/Camera-intrinsics-database and http://argus.web.unc.edu/camera-calibration-database/ in the first hits, probably there are more. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889200/is-there-a-camera-calibration-matrix-database too

Comment: For ARKit, the `ARCamera` [`instrinsics`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2875730-intrinsics) property tells you what you need. Dunno about android though.